# Call value from PyQt5 UI interface and carry out operation in another py file

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am new to Python and still learning.

I have a py file that I generated ftom Qt designer (ForEmail.py):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QTimer


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(398, 235)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 161, 121))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.frame)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(92, 33, 51, 19))
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 52, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(11, 31, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 398, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "HS_DELAY"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "HOT START"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am trying to get the number from the spin box entry to be used as the number for a timer that goes on and carries out the operation of keeping the button pressed while showing some text while the button is presseed (Hot_Strt_Test.py):

```
class Hot_Strt_Test_Btn():
    def __init__(self, pushButton_object):          
        bt3_timer = 10
        self.count = bt3_timer
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Action)
        self.time = QTimer(self.pushButton)
        self.time.setInterval(1000)
        self.time.timeout.connect(self.Refresh)
        #self.show()

    def Action(self):
        if self.pushButton.isEnabled():
            self.time.start()
            self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)

    def Refresh(self):
        bt3_timer = 10
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton"
                                "{"
                                "background-color : red;"
                                "}") 
        if self.count > 0:
            self.pushButton.setText('HOT START RUNNING\n'+str(self.count)+' secs')
            self.count -= 1
        else:
            self.time.stop()
            self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.pushButton.setText('HOT START')
            self.count = bt3_timer
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton"
                                "{"
                                "background-color : lightgray;"
                                "}")
```

Currently I'm not getting the operation as described.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: How is `Hot_Strt_Test_Btn` instantiated? Please provide a [mre]. Also consider that you should normally follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (which is, by subclassing the QWidget type you're going to call `setupUi()` onto).

Comment: @musicamante, thanks for your input.  It will be iniated by the `pushButton.cliked.connect(self.Action)`??

Comment: Please read more carefully what I asked. We need to know how the instance of that class is created. Provide a MRE as asked.